# why I am geeing command not found after executing this code?

Tags: bash

I am storing location of files in one file and reading it to access actual files

format of the file is lets say `filename.txt` in that I have

```
random lines 
............
............
............
............
............
Density:      12.157% random text
```

I want to extract density value from this file and I have written following code

```
declare -A data

tempVar=""
RUNCOUNT=1
FILENAME=$1
while read line
do
    data[$RUNCOUNT]=$line
    data[$RUNCOUNT]['Density']=`grep "Density:"  $line | tail -1 | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+"`  
    tempVar=${data[$RUNCOUNT]['Density']}
    echo "$tempVar"
    RUNCOUNT=$((RUNCOUNT+1))
done < $FILENAME
```

I am getting following output

```
data[1][Density]=12.157: command not found filename.txt
```

why I am getting command not found when executed.

Comment: Because you are writing syntax that does not exist. There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Bash.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek is there any workaround to use multidimensional arrays something like dictionary in python ?

Comment: Yes, but in this particular case it makes more sense just to use separate arrays -- one `data`, one `densities`, with identical keys so `data[1]` corresponds to `densities[1]`.